In VS Code, where do you find the HTML and CSS to create a sidebar navigation for your website?
I want to use HTML and CSS to create a vertical sidebar navigation for my Wordpress website. Where can I access the Html & CSS in Visual Studio Code?

You have to download HTML and CSS for VS Code if you haven't already (Chances are that they are already downloaded). After doing so, Create a folder in the directory and add 2 new files in the folder with the file types .html and .css
open both files side by side and start working on your website.

I think the OP was asking where to find the source files for editing wordpress sidebar, the question does not look to be really about VS Code.
